# How do I split and isolate a digital signal?

Tags: opto-isolator, signal-processing, phototransistor

I am working on a circuit that needs to observe when VAC is at zero cross. I have a photostransistor whose anode and cathode are connected to VAC line and neutral. I've connected 3.3VDC to the collector side of the transistor. My logic chip watches the emitter side of the phototransistor with an internal pulldown GPIO. When the emitter reads a digital false, I know VAC is briefly at zero cross.

I want to use the output from the emitter to power a VAC status indicator LED, but I don't want to interfere with the zero cross monitor (since the signal is being pulled down). Is there a device that is commonly used to split a signal into two isolated signals? So the GPIO PD doesn't interfere with the LED.

[image: Example circuit schematic for clarity]

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answeres pull down/up is supposed to be there when there is no signal. Suppose the Vac signal is at the very brief moment of zero cross, and the BJT is open, that is when the pull-down brings the observing node voltage to zero => LED is OFF. Then again the moment is very brief.  Depending on the Vac amplitude, this brief moment might be missed as the phototransistor photodiode might be turned on for the majority of the AC cycle, hence the LED might be turned on for the majority of the time. A bit more information can be helpful like what signals do you want to split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why you you ask about how to split a signal, maybe because you think splitting a signal is a solution to your original problem, about pull-down interfering a LED, but you don't need to split the signal to begin with because pull-down isn't a problem.

The pull down is in the order of 50k, and it pulls down. A 50k pull-down won't interfere with the LED.

Comment: I had a PCB fabricated and was running into an issue where if I enabled the PD on the GPIO, the blue LED would get super dim and difficult to see through the tinted acrylic viewport of my device. The logic chip I'm using is the MSP432E401Y. I am somewhat new to electronics, could it be that the phototransistor (FODM2705) isn't supplying enough current from collector to emitter?

Comment: @Dan Sorry but if a weak pull-down in the order of tens of kilo-ohms dims your LED, either there is a hardware issue and the circuit was barely working to begin with, or, there is a software issue and you did not activate a pull-down but are setting the pin as low output. Both are not good. On the other side, blue LEDs have extemely high forward voltage and require near 3.3V to light up, so it is anyway a bad idea to run blue LEDs at 3.3V.

Comment: I agree that both of those scenarios would not good. The pin is configured as an input with a pulldown, and is not being set low as an output. I think I may have misunderstood the current transfer ratio of the phototransistor?

Comment: The datasheet for the phototransistor says it has a minimum CTR of 50% @ 5mA, and a maximum CTR of 300% @ 5mA. Does this mean that the current through the collector to the emitter is a ratio of the current from the cathode to the diode? Am I just misunderstanding this completely?

Comment: @Dan That is correct. For 5mA in, the output could be 2.5mA to 15mA. But how much is your input? It's 12 or 24 mA peak?

Comment: It is 12mA peak! My led draws the typical 20mA. I should increase it to 24mA peak?

Comment: If your opto input AC is 120VAC, with 10k resistor the opto input is 12mA peak, making the series resistor drop more than 1W. The blue LED can't draw 20mA. Why? If it did, there would be 2V over the 100 ohm resistor, leaving 1.3V over the blue LED, and that's contrary to common knowledge how blue LEDs work. Indeed, maybe it would be better to drive the blue LED from a higher supply throgh a transistor or something. But I checked; the internal pull-down of the MCU is about 20k, it cannot load down an othwise properly working circuit. I don't suggest you spend more watts on opto input resistor.